# Generic Interface mess

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to encapsulate 3 interfaces in one (`ICountable`) and make concrete class implement this encapsulating interface. `` `ICountable `` code:

```
public interface ICountable extends IAddable, Cloneable, Serializable {}
```

`Addable` interface definition is:

```
public interface IAddable<T> {
    T add(T other);
}
```

now when I am trying to implement `ICountable` in the concrete class (`BaseCounter`) I am getting the error that not all methods are implemented (complaining on `add` method). I fail to understand why. The `BaseCounter` code is as follows:

```
public class BaseCounter implements ICountable {
    @Override
    public BaseCounter add(BaseCounter other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Change `add` method signature to

```
public ICountable add(ICountable other)
```

fixes the situation.
However, what I wanted originally, was to make one interface (`ICountable`) that extends 3 others (2 markers and 1 interface that describes the ability of the implementing class to perform `add` on the object of the same type). What I need to change in order to make `add` method implementation in `BaseCounter` look like this:

```
public BaseCounter add(BaseCounter other)
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 Add generic to ICountable

```
public interface ICountable<T> extends IAddable<T>, Cloneable, Serializable {}
```

2 Specify generic in implementation

```
public class BaseCounter implements ICountable<BaseCounter> {
    @Override
    public BaseCounter add(BaseCounter other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are wellcome. You can add some extends to generic for restriction that add should accept only ICountable: public interface ICountable<T extends ICountable> extends IAddable<T>, Cloneable, Serializable {}. In this case only ICountable implementations may be accepted as generic type.

Answer (score 3):

Without having compiled the code I think you need to add generic types to the interfaces. If the types are not passed along to the interfaces, the methods have no way of knowing which return-type to give (except ICountable of course, which you also mentioned, worked). Example

```
public interface IAddable<T> { 
    T add(T other);
}

public interface ICountable<T> extends IAddable<T>, ... {
    ....
}

public class BaseCounter implements IAddable<T> {
    @Override public BaseCounter add(BaseCounter other) { ... }
}
```

This ought to fix the problem..

Comment: thanks! Pretty same idea like in alexey28's. I upvote (but the accept goes to him since he was the 1st :))

Comment: public class BaseCounter implements IAddable<T> - foget to change generic T to BaseCounter